# How can I incorporate an image map into a fluid layout?

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, liquid-layout

I am currently having a huge headache trying to get a site I'm building to work across variable resolutions. The main navigation is through an image map that needs to fill most of the viewport. I know this is totally outmoded but an image map seems the only non-Flash solution to allow polygonal area delimiting - i'd *love* an alternative though!

I have eventually managed to get the site to resize to allow the main image to display on smaller monitors using conditional jQuery & CSS, but that resizes the text within the slickboxes too, which looks awful!

The site (very much unfinished) is [here](http://www.artforeating.co.uk/portia/rainbowwhitebgscale.html). I know the navigation isn't entirely clear yet (hover over and click paint colours), but I want to sort this issue first.

My questions, in summary:

1. Is there an alternative way to create this polygonal hotspot rollover image without using an Image Map?
2. Is there otherwise a way of resizing the image map and overlaid slickboxes, while keeping text the same size?

Thanks so much - been pulling hair out over this all weekend!

Comment: I faced this problem myself before, but I never found a solution. I'm interested to see what answers come up.

Comment: @casablanca I edited my answer with the only approach I can think of now that relative values don't work

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The percent approach doesn't work.

In that case, the only thing I can see goes like this:

Have shapes using percent notation:

```
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,0,0" mycoords="1%,3%,25%,29%">
```

On the first draw and on every window resize:

- parse each area's `mycoords` property
- Split percentages into four integers
- Calculate percentages based on the image's `.width()` property
- Set the area's `coords` property based on the thusly calculated pixel values

Not entirely trivial, but this should be halfway easy to implement by a seasoned jQueryist.

**Old answer:**

Hmm. So you have an imagemap that needs to resize dynamically?

I have never tried this myself, but what about using relative coordinates=

```
 <area shape="rect" coords="1%,3%,25%,29%">
```

No idea whether this works, but worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I just tested this in Firefox and it completely ignores the `%`, interpreting the numbers as pixel coordinates.

Comment: @casablanca, same result on Chrome

Comment: @casablanca @Harmen crap. In that case, the only thing I can think of is resizing it dynamically using jQuery/Javascript. Thanks for testing it out.

Comment: @Pekka: Indeed that works, though I would've liked a cleaner way of doing it. Image maps can come in really handy at times and it's a pity that they've been forgotten for ages now.

Comment: @casablanca yeah. I'm really disappointed that relative values don't work, it would be so easy to implement for a browser

Comment: @Pekka: And it's not just 4 coordinates. Polygonal areas can have arbitrarily many pairs and circular areas are defined with `x,y,radius`. It's really messy having to handle all this manually in JavaScript.

Comment: @casablanca I know, but it's not impossible. Messy, but possible. There ought to be a jQuery plugin!

Comment: @Pekka: Sure, it's possible, but once again, I guess there aren't too many people using image maps any more, hence the lack of any ready-made plugins.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, casablanca! Indeed there should be a ready-made plugin, as sadly I'm not a seasoned jQueryist, but merely a dabbler in scripts.

I did come up with an alternative solution however, whereby I recalculated the coords offline and created a lower resolution version of the page, which is now served based on screen.width - see here http://www.artforeating.co.uk/portia/detectpage.html

It seems to work pretty well! Is this a terrible idea?

Comment: @James sounds like an all right idea to me! If it works for all resolutions 
*somehow*, I can't see anything wrong with this

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit limited, but you CAN do irregular shapes with HTML/CSS.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/d/sprites/ala-blobs2.html)

[CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/imagemap-revisited.html)

You should be able to adapt one of those to your purposes.

**EDIT:**

Regarding image resizing, you need to use relative widths in your CSS instead of hardcoding them in pixels

In fact, there is a flexible framework that may already take care of much of that for you:
[Check out CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/).

Comment: This is interesting (good links!) but doesn't help with the resizing problem, does it?

Comment: but relative widths don't work in the image map, that was the problem we are discussing above

Comment: That's correct. My proposal to you is to drop the image map, and incorporate the links I gave in to the project which will fake it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around for hotspots in a fluid design is to make a responsive static image with links in Edge Animate.
The hotspots (or layers that act as hotspots) are then totally responsive. The downside being that a 50kb image will be about 120kb's when output from Edge. Having said that its a pretty quick work around.